# Parar o loop quando achar um resultado

Tags: java, loop

```
public Objeto busca(String nome){
    for(Objeto id : MinhaLista){
        if(id.getNome().equals(nome)){
            return null;
        } else {                
            return id;
        }                   
    }
}
```

este é o codigo, ele está retornando o **id** ou **null** repetidamente. como faço pra parar o loop quando achar o resultado e só retornar apenas um resultado ao invés de vários?

Comment: Voce pode usar `break` quando encontrar o resultado.

Comment: Este código não faz sentido e se está repetindo o problema está na chamada do método `busca`. Note que isto será executado apenas uma vez sempre. Na primeira interação, ele vai cair em um dos dois blocos do `if` e em ambos existe um `return` encerrando o método.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vejamos o seu código:

```java
public Objeto busca(String nome){
    for(Objeto id : MinhaLista){
        if(id.getNome().equals(nome)){
            return null;
        } else {                
            return id;
        }                   
    }
}
```

Quando ele começa a iterar o primeiro elemento, se o nome coincidir com o esperado, retorna `null`, e quando não coincidir retorna este objeto.

Isto não está certo. Ele sempre retorna na primeira iteração! Além disso, ele só retorna o primeiro elemento se ele **não** for o que você procura. Se for o que você procura ele não retorna nada! Isso não tem sentido.

Acho que o que você queria é isso:

```java
public Objeto busca(String nome){
    for(Objeto id : MinhaLista){
        if(id.getNome().equals(nome)){
            // Achou o que queria, retorna.
            return id;
        }                   
    }
    return null; // Tentou todos e não achou nenhum, desiste.
}
```

Como sugerido pelo Felipe Fonseca em um comentário, vale a pena tratar os `null`s e evitar `NullPointerException`s:

```java
public Objeto busca(String nome){
    Objects.requireNonNull(nome, "O nome do objeto a buscar deve ser informado.");
    for(Objeto id : MinhaLista){
        if(nome.equals(id.getNome())){
            // Achou o que queria, retorna.
            return id;
        }                   
    }
    return null; // Tentou todos e não achou nenhum, desiste.
}
```

Estou assumindo que `MinhaLista` não contém elementos `null` nela porque isso não costuma ter sentido. Se isso ocorre, você pode adicionar um `if (id == null) continue;` antes deste outro `if` que já está no código.

Comment: Vale adicionar um tratamento ao NullPointer no código para evitar exceções indesejadas

Comment: @FelipeFonseca Ok, editado. Muito obrigado. :)

Comment: sou grato pela ajuda. positivei.

Comment: @JoseMaximilian Valeu, obrigado! Também positivei você. :)